# Race condition between two network clients

Tags: networking, distributed, race-condition

I have the following problem: I have two network clients, where one is a device that is to be "claimed" by its owner, and another is the program which claims it. When the claimee hits the server, it announces it's available to be claimed, and then the claimer can claim it (after authenticating and supplying information only it could know of course). However, if claimer hits the server first, then I have a classic "lost signal" problem. The claimer can retry and that's fine, but I can end up with the following race condition, the main point in question:

Claimee hits the server and announces, then its connection fails
Claimer comes in and find the announced record, and claims it
Claimee reconnects with a status of unclaimed, and overwrites the claim

I've thought of a few solutions:

1) Expire old claimee announces after 60 seconds, and have the claimer retry. This is still susceptible to the above problem, but shrinks the window to about 60 seconds. In addition, the claimee takes about 30-40 seconds to bootstrap, so it should pragmatically make the problem very hard to encounter, or reproduce.

2) Have claims issued by claimer be valid for any claimee announce up to 30 seconds after the claim came in. This works, but starts to muddle the definition of a claimee announce: it means that the claimee announce isn't always interpreted to mean to "reset the claimee status," because for up to 30 seconds after the last claim it means "join to last claim."

Those are the high points, but may not be enough of a description of the problem, so let me know if I can add any comments to elucidate further. In terms of the solution, these are workable solutions, but I'm looking for an analogy to a known problem perhaps, and to see if there're ideas I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn’t understand the problem description correctly, but you have also another problem - what if both are connected just fine and than the claimee fails? The claimer will need to deal with this issue as well, unless you’re assuming that this scenario never can happen.

In general there are several ways to implement a solution for both problems, but the probably most reliable one would be inspired by the implementation used by Java’s RMI.

When you send a message to the claimee add there a unique ID. When you don’t get an answer you can retry sending the message several times with the same ID (messages can get lost) and after some longer timeout you can accept that the claimee is unavailable. Now you can again look for connection information at the server and restart the process.

For this you’d need to cache all messages which haven’t been yet processed on claimer’s side. Additionally on claimee’s side you’ll need to cache the last X message IDs and their results (if available) This is necessary in order not to perform operations in one message multiple times and also be able to reply with the correct result again (since also result messages can get lost)